# Banned IPs check before anything else in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I have a table with IP/DNS data for banned visitors. I want this check to be done before anything else, but after the model for banned IPs is loaded.

What is the best place to add this code and make it run every time a page is accessed, taking into account that it should load a view for the 403 error to be displayed for banned visitors?

The banned visitors model is loaded globally (specified in *autoload.php*). Now, I only need to make the function that verifies if the visitor is banned global. Can this be done using hooks? What do you recommend?

Comment: Have you considered NOT touching your framework of choice and having the webserver handle it for you?

Comment: I will take that into consideration, too. I don't know how that htaccess would look like after banning quite a few IPs. Also, the load on the web server vs the load on the database + PHP execution. Apart from that, I might want to add a reason and duration for the bans, which the banned visitors should see in the 403 page

Comment: You could take a look at iptables - very useful for sysadmins :-)

Comment: A peasant with a web hosting plan can't go that far, I fear. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create in the application/core folder a controller named MY_Controller.

The Controller should look like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bannedIpAdresses();
    }

    private function bannedIpAdresses()
    {
        $this->load->model("BannedIps_Model");

        if ($this->BannedIps_Model->isIpBanned())
        {
            $this->load->view("restricted");
            die();
        }

    }
}
```

and every other Controller like the welcome Controller should look like

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```